# Set random seed in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I am currently filling a vector with random numbers using `Eigen::VectorXd::Random(n)`.

Is it possible to seed Eigen's random number generator for deterministic results? Or alternatively, pass a random number generator to Eigen? I found no mention of either in the Eigen wiki, but it seems odd that such a feature would be missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It calls rand() from the standard library. You can set the seed by
calling srand().

Matrix::Random uses the random number generator of the standard library, so you can initialize the random number sequence with srand(unsigned int seed), for instance:

`srand((unsigned int) time(0));`